# How to pdf two pics overlying in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I ggploted two pics a & b, and I could print them in one pic. But I want to use code like this "`ggsave(file='o.png',plot = ...,width=10,dpi=600)`" to output them.
How should I change my code? Thanks

```
  library(grid)
  vie <- viewport(width=0.1,height=0.15,x=0.7,y=0.3) 
  a
  print(b,vp=vie)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145252/how-to-save-inset-viewport-plots-into-pdf-file-using-grid-and-ggplot2-packages, see this question it may answer yours

Comment: It does help. Thanks!